# How to parse error response body in OpenFeign and return it like success response

Tags: feign, openfeign

My application needs to behave 200 OK for all failure responses just like a business error. When response is 4xx or 5xx, ErrorDecoder runs and it needs to return Exception. However, I want to parse error message body and just return it.

Here is the response format and i can distinguish whether the response is success or fail by checking **responseCode** attribute in response body.

`{ "responseCode" : responseCode, "details" : "....", "data" : {..} }`

I did set ErrorDecoder while creating FeignClient in below.

```
Feign.builder()
    .encoder(encoder)
    .decoder(decoder)
    .errorDecoder(new CustomErrorDecoder())
    .target(clazz, "uri");


class FeignClientExceptionHandler implements ErrorDecoder {
      @Override
      public Exception decode(String methodKey, Response response) {
         ...
      }
}
```

Is there any way to convert error response body to dto without throwing exception ?
Thanks in advance.

I checked open feign documentation and did not find any solution.
https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign